# How can i call a Sub using hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel

I am newbie to VBA; I have a question:

How can I call sub to delete a cell in a sheet by using a Hyperlinks from another sheet.

A structure of the code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handler in worksheet which contains the hyperlink:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    If Target.TextToDisplay = "Clear Cell" Then
        ClearThatCell
    End If

End Sub
```

Note there's also a Workbook-level event: use that if you'd like to be able to trap any hyperlink click in the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, _
                                      ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

End Sub
```

Called code:

```
Sub ClearThatCell()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
' Public m_data_wks As Worksheet
Sub init_links
  Dim v_r As Range, n_rows as Integer
  Set v_r = m_data_wks.Cells(1, 1)
  n_rows = 3 'is an example of filling up cells with hyperlinks
  For I = 1 To n_rows
    v_r.Value = I
    'The key: adding hyperlink to the v_r cell with a special subaddress for alternative usage.
    'The hyperlink looks like the ordinary but points to itself.
    m_data_wks.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=v_r, Address:="", SubAddress:=v_r.Address(External:=False, RowAbsolute:=False, columnAbsolute:=False)
    Set v_r = v_r.Offset(1)
  Next I
end sub

'Private WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub App_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
  Dim v_dst As Worksheet, v_index_s As String, v_index_i As Integer
  'get_context sets v_dst the proper worksheet
  'get_context Sh.Parent, v_dst
  If v_dst Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo Ext
  'Using the value of the cell for choosing which to delete
  v_index_s = CStr(Sh.Range(Target.SubAddress).Value)
  If v_index_s = "#" Then
    v_index_i = 0
  Else
    v_index_i = CLng(v_index_s)
  End If
  'Here the v_index_i points to the row instead of a cell for deleting
  v_dst.Rows(v_index_i).Delete
  Exit Sub
Ext:
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error occured while deleting by hyperlink: " & Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Non critical error"
    Err.Clear
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I understood how it is working.
But i have an issue now: of how to put this code using macro into the newly created worksheet which i populated with hyperlinks.

Comment: @Alexey Open VBA Editor (Alt+F11) -> Expand project of the newly created worksheet -> Add a new class module (for handling events with the `App` field) -> Copy and Paste the code samples, adding the commented fields -> Edit the methods to adapt for your task -> Save the worksheet as a worksheet with macroses. Another approach is making Add-in, wich is to be installed in order to macros work. Also the ready VBAProject may be programmatically attached using OpenXML SDK and [Office File Formats Technical Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank's Aleksej. I got it and it works fine.
Just now i am stuck of how to reference back to a specific type of hyperlink named "Delete", because i have other hyperlinks with different names. But i need to use only the one named "Delete". Could you give me a hint please?

Comment: @Alexey If you have only the one link `Delete`, you need to trace the active cell in order to save the last range selected by user before clicking `Delete`: when the link is clicked, the `ActiveCell` is already the range of the link. But in this case you should use another approach: open the `Developer` ribbon, then drop an Excel (not ActiveX) button, name it `Delete` and assign macros to be run. In such a case you don't need to trace active cell due to it is not changed when the button is clicked. (PS And what about the usefulness of my answer?)

Comment: Alexej, unfortunately i still can't post any "usefulness check mark" to your answer because i still don't have enough of points to do that.
 But for the button thank's i will try to do that.